# Need SQL-Regexp help: Find lowercase char before uppercase char

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, request

I need a mySQL request where I only find strings which contains a uppercase character before a lowercase char within a single word.

Example: **fooExample**

In best case only if there are at least 2 characters before the uppercase char.
So it should not find: "**iPhone**" for example.
And it must be a real char in range from a-z before A-Z.

I guess I should use the SQL function REGEXP, but I can't get it working because I'm not very familiar with regular expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from table where binary(your_field) regexp '^[a-z]{2,}[A-Z]+'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT col
FROM tableName
WHERE col REGEXP '[a-z]{2}[A-Z]'
```

Comment: +1. I misunderstood and made the check only at the beginning of the string. :)